# Getting undefined local variable or method using Action Cable calling class method from model, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am getting a error using action cable,

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `connections_info' for MicropostNotificationsChannel:Class):

app/channels/micropost_notifications_channel.rb:12:in `notify'
app/models/notification.rb:8:in `block in <class:Notification>'
app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:11:in `create'
Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
...
```

To my knowledge and from using controllers and models I can call the class method `after_commit -> {MicropostNotificationsChannel.notify(self)}` and then get to the `self.notifiy(notification)` and then as `connections_info` is a instance method I should be able to call it inside that class and carry out my code but I get the error here?

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  after_commit -> {MicropostNotificationsChannel.notify(self)}
end
```

The action cable micropost notification channel

```
class MicropostNotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def subscribe
    ...
  end

  def unsubscribe
    ...
  end

  def self.notifiy(notification)
    connection_results = connections_info
    puts connection_results.inspect
  end
end
```

Channel.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base

    def connections_info
      # do stuff here
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `connections_info` as an instance method in `ApplicationCable::Channel`, but `notify` is a class method and so it's looking for methods at the class level instead of the instance level. Sometimes classes will get around this by using `method_missing`, but it doesn't look like Action Cable does that at a glance. Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, it's hard to say whether to change `connections_info` to a class method, `notify` to an instance method, or something else.

Comment: `connections_info` is getting all the user objects that `ActionCable` has stored so I can get who is on what channel and SAVE notification records to the db as well as push dynamic notifications. I am able to call `notfify` as a instance method from `subscribe` when a connection is established. But I do not want to call it from there. I never knew that you had to call a instance method from within a instance method not a class method. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Sorry I think i get that now. Thanks you! Am I able to ask, I would need to get a hold of the ActionCable instance that is used?

Comment: @LeeEather I'm not super familiar with Action Cable so it might make sense to ask a separate question. But looking at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html, it looks like the recommended way to send notifications is to call `stream_from` or `stream_for` in the `subscribed` callback and then call `MicropostNotificationsChannel.broadcast_to(...)`. You don't necessarily need to know who all the users are at any one time unless you're doing something more advanced.

Comment: Thanks @max. I have set up action cable like you said, but it is more advanced. I want to create notifications for when a user subscribes to a post, so not only like you said use `stream_from` to connect the user/s to the post I also want to record a record in the db for each user connected when the notification is created. So trying to tap into the ActionCable instance is what I am looking for, it keeps a copy on the client side for each user but looking into how I can get the `MicropostNotificationsChannel` instance. Doesnt help I am still novice at ruby, but I'll see how I go!

Comment: @LeeEather Yeah, probably best to ask a new question focusing on that. You might get some people with more Action Cable experience than me to weigh in!

Comment: Yeah np. I was able to solve this as you said, using class methods and switched from a instance of the `connection.server` method I was using, to ActionCables singleton method of the server `ActionCable.server`

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when your redis configuration is not correct.